# Why colored text is not shown in terminal? Python

Tags: python, terminal, ansi-colors

I'm trying to print some colored text, however every method I tried failed, the Interpreter just prints the color codes as well with the text, it does not change the color any ideas why?
I am using Python 3.6.8 on a Windows 10 Pro computer

Here is a code sample:

```
print("Blah blah \033[0;32mthis part will be green\033[00m blah blah.")
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of Windows? You'll need Windows 10 or higher. This answer for a similar C question says use `system(" ")` to turn on VT emulation... which in the python world would be `os.system(" ")` ... I think ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125110/642070

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, I am using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: No, already tried this and I get the same output

Comment: @drec4s - That's a useful alternate but I don't think it answers the question of using ansi codes so can't be a duplicate.

Comment: Microsoft's [Console Virtual Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) docs reference [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) which you should be able to call from the win32 extensions or ctypes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be stuck, I managed to do it with [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) just be sure to call init().